# Configuration error after deploying asp.net files into iis server alternative

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, iis, deployment

I am getting the following error which deploying my code in the production server. Code is working fine in development.

```
Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (E:\QA\form\web.config line 103)

Source Error: 


Line 101:       </httpHandlers>
Line 102:       <httpModules>
Line 103:           <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
Line 104:       </httpModules>
Line 105:   </system.web>


Source File: E:\QA\form\web.config    Line: 103 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3053; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3053
```

I know this is because :

The server doesn't have .NET 3.5 SP1 installed on it. and code is depending on the .Net 3.5 runtime, but my server only has .Net 2.0.I need at least the ASP.NET AJAX 1.0 download, which should run with .Net 2.0.

But unfortunately i cannot install any of these in my production server. Do we have any other fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

No.  If you can't install the dependencies your application requires on the production server, then you must either (1) remove the dependencies from your application that are not present in your production environment (i.e. do things another way); or (2) not deploy in that environment.  But, it seems strange that you would not be able to install the latest version of the Framework.  Also, you should probably try and better understand the restrictions of your production environment before you develop to a certain Framework level.